# call event asynchronously in wcf service

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I am implementing a third party service to get some feeds. sample code below. 
when I call the GetLiveFeed function the response is returned through an event HandleEvent.

```
public class WebComponent
{
    public string livefeed = string.Empty;

    public static string GetSerivceRequest()
    {
        WebComponent obj = new WebComponent();
        obj.GetResult();

        return obj.livefeed;
    }

    public void GetResult()
    {
        Service abc = new Service();
        abc.GetLiveFeed();
    }

    public void HandleEvent(Event eventObj)
    {
        livefeed = "Value from third party service";
    }

}
```

I want to wait in the static function Getservice until the event is raised and value is assigned in the livefeed variable. 
But as of now I am only getting blank value. if I put thread.sleep than I get value which I don't want to use

Comment: You cannot await events which I'll admit is annoying to deal with. One workaround I've found for this is using a semaphore with only 1 entry. Then you can wait for it while `abc.GetLiveFeed()` is executed and you only release it when the event is finished. But I'm not quite sure how "accepted" this approach is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the parent thread wait until the execution finishes in the child thread using AutoresetEvent functionality

[Tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_AutoResetEvent)